# Old Science Fiction anthology: man with nightmares of a giant bee; post-apocalyptic underground world

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, dinosaurs

I found this site today while searching for a book and hope someone can help.

When I was a boy I read a hard-bound anthology of science fiction stories. This was circa 1986, but the book might have already been a little old.

I can only remember three stories:

- One was about a man working in space who had nightmares of his impending death by a giant bee. This ultimately cost him his life when he was killed while working on the outside of his spaceship, that was in the shape of a bee (or some other insect, but I think it was a bee). The front cover MIGHT have been a picture of this bee-looking spaceship, but I'm not entirely sure. I remember the picture, but it might have been within the story.
- Another story was about a post-apocalyptic world where humanity had long moved underground for protection while rockets were still firing off in a long-forgotten war. Children became rarer and most families had synthetic children. A boy and a girl, who were friends, decided to escape to the surface mostly guided by their curiosity I think. They find out that the rockets were being exploded immediately by robots (as far as I remember) and that there was really nothing to be afraid of on the surface. Their flimsy suits quickly dissolved or something in the air or water and at the very end we got to know that their names were Adam and Eve.
- The last story of the book was about dinosaurs that got loose. Possibly kind of Jurassic Park on another planet, and how the humans escaped.

I would really appreciate it if anybody can help. It's like an itch I cannot scratch and would really like to find this book, having children of my own now :)

Comment: Your question has been marked as a Duplicate. Please understand that this is not a censure, just bookkeeping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've got a 2 out of 3 match.

The second story is "[The Children](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2030202)" by Malcom Hulke. The third story might be "[Day of the Dinosaurs](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2030225)" by Jim Stories. Both appear in *[Galactic Adventures](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?362855)*, aka *Purnell's Book of Adventures in Space*. That's the only place they're known to appear. Unfortunately, no story about a ship shaped like a bee.

This book was a cherished memory for many as per [Looking for sci-fi short story anthology with a particular story of an Earth/Mars war children inheriting the surface](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175036/looking-for-sci-fi-short-story-anthology-with-a-particular-story-of-an-earth-mar) and other times it's come up on the site.

Comment: That's EXACTLY the book I was looking for: Purnell's Book of Adventures in Space. From the stories in the list I now realise that the bee one may have been from another anthology, but the stories bring back the memories and the cover is definitely familiar. Many many thanks @FuzzyBoots   I HAD tried to look up references on this website, but was not successful, probably because I missed some keywords.

Comment: No worries. The search can be finicky. Using Google, e.g. `site:scifi.stackexchange.com story dinosaurs children robots`, can get more approximate matches.